# How to set Activation Policy before launch application?

Tags: swift, macos

I‘m trying to create an application which have a two state: default and background. If it will be launched as usual (by clicking an app icon on launchpad or double clicking in Finder)app icon will be present in the dock and main window  will shown. And if launch with `openApplication(at:configuration:completionHandler:)` `NSWorkspace` method application must be 'background' without icon in dock and window. More over when the app in background mode and user click an app icon on launchpad or double click in Finder app icon must become appear in dock and main window must opened.

Is there a way set Activation Policy before launch application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just answer your question, there is indeed a way to set activation policy before launch.

Here's how a simple demo of how to do that:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct my_super_cool_app: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup() {
            TestView(appDelegate: appDelegate)
        }
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate
    @State private var hideInDock: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Hide in Dock", isOn: $hideInDock)
                .onChange(of: hideInDock) { newValue in
                    let policy: NSApplication.ActivationPolicy = newValue ? .accessory : .regular
                    appDelegate.updateActivationPolicy(to: policy)
                    
                    
                }
        }.padding()
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
    }
    func updateActivationPolicy(to policy: NSApplication.ActivationPolicy) {
            NSApp.setActivationPolicy(policy)
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }
}
```

You can use AppDelegateAdaptor to control the initial state of the app as well as change the current activation policy. Changing the policy to be .accessory autohides the app, so you also need to activate your app immediately after.